# Filter dataframe by line row

Tags: python, pandas, filter, merge

Hi I am a beginner python user and I need some help.  I am trying to filter one dataframe against another.

Df1

```
 date          emp#   sku     transaction#   
 2017-01-01    10     200     399              
 2017-01-01    10     201     399             
 2017-01-01    10     202     399             
 2017-01-01    11     203     399             
 2017-01-01    11     200     399
```

Df2

```
 date          emp#   sku     transaction#
 2017-01-01    10     200     301
 2017-01-01    11     200     301
```

Desired
Df1

```
 date          emp#   sku     transaction#
 2017-01-01    10     200     399
 2017-01-01    11     200     399
```

I know this can work with an inner join (one emp# and sku) but I would have erroneous columns, how can I do this as a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way without `pd.merge`. The benefit of this method is you don't have to play around with column names.

```
df2 = df2.set_index(['emp#', 'sku'])
df2['transaction#'] = df1.set_index(['emp#', 'sku'])['transaction#']
df2 = df2.reset_index()

#    emp#  sku        date  transaction#
# 0    10  200  2017-01-01           399
# 1    11  200  2017-01-01           399
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `merge` and the `on` parameter:

```
Df1.merge(Df2, on=['date','emp#','sku'], suffixes=('','_y'))\
   .drop('transaction#_y', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
         date  emp#  sku  transaction#
0  2017-01-01    10  200           399
1  2017-01-01    11  200           399
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a filter from `df2` by converting the desired columns into a dictionary, with orientation set to `list`, and then check in the values exist using `isin`. Lastly, take the `min` of each row to ensure both conditions are met i.e.

1. `False` + `False` = `False`
2. `False` + `True` = `False`
3. `True` + `False` = `False`
4. `True` + `True` = `True`

---

```
cols = ['emp#','sku']
df1[df1[cols].isin(df2[cols].to_dict(orient='list')).min(1)]

         date  emp#  sku  transaction#
0  2017-01-01    10  200           399
4  2017-01-01    11  200           399
```

Answer (score -1):

You need an inner join it looks like: keeps rows that are only in both:

```
df1.join(df2, how='inner')
```

Comment: Probably drop the column you don't want from df2 before the join; this will keep the wrong "sku" from being used.